# How to call django-pipeline compressor with jinja2 templates

Tags: django, jinja2, minify, django-pipeline, google-app-engine-python

I wish to compress the JS and CSS in my Jinja2 based Python project for Google App engine.
I have installed django-pipeline, and added it to my project path.

Some of the [documentation](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) is not clear to me. Particularly Jinja2 usage.

For Django Templates, in base.html [example](http://www.glenrobertson.co.nz/blog/2013/02/04/django-js-css-compression-with-pipeline.html), insert:

```
{% load compressed %}
{% compressed_css 'colors' %}
{% compressed_js 'stats' %}
```

I assume the equivalent for Jina2 would be something like

```
{{ compressed_css("main") }}
{{ compressed_js("main") }}
```

But this gives
UndefinedError: 'compressed_css' is undefined

My question is  **how to load the 'compressed' template in Jinja2?** This is not done in the same way as Django and I can't find an example.

The docs also say

> In order to use Django Compressor’s Jinja2 extension we would need to
>   pass compressor.contrib.jinja2ext.CompressorExtension into
>   environment:

I have done that.

```
import jinja2
from compressor.contrib.jinja2ext import CompressorExtension
env = jinja2.Environment(extensions=[CompressorExtension])
```

The docs also state

> "Unlike the Django template tag implementation the Jinja2
>   implementation uses different templates, so if you wish to override
>   them please override pipeline/css.jinja and pipeline/js.jinja."

I am not sure if I need to do anything here.

My setings.py includes the following statements:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = '{{ project_name }}.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = '{{ project_name }}.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates"),
    os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "templates/includes")
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'django_jinja.contrib._pipeline',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)


SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder'
)
PIPELINE_ENABLE = True
PIPELINE_JS_COMPRESSOR = 'pipeline.compressors.closure.ClosureCompressor'
PIPELINE_CLOSURE_BINARY = 'C:\bunjilsrc\tools\minify\minify.bat'
PIPELINE_DISABLE_WRAPPER = True
PIPELINE_ENABLE_GAE_SUPPORT = True

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'  
STATIC_URL = '/static/'  
MEDIA_ROOT = 'uploads/'  
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"  

PIPELINE_JS = {
    'main': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'js/site.js '
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/main.js'
    },
    'vendor': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'js/vendor/jquery.js',
        ),
        'output_filename': 'js/vendor.js'
    }
}

PIPELINE_CSS = {
    'main': {
        'source_filenames': (
            'bootstrap.css',
            'site.css'
                ),
        'output_filename': 'css/main.css'
    }
}
```

Comment: The correct syntax for a seems to be {%{javascript 'main' %} {%{stylesheet 'main' %} However, it does not load the PIPELINE_JS dictionary in settings.py. 
Pipeline 1.5 adds support for Django 1.8 but drops support for Django 1.6. However google-app-engine only supports Django 1.5.8. So there could be compatibility issues. There are no public examples of projects using jinja2 templates, django-pipeline and app engine. Try something else?

Answer (score 0):

Going to describe things which worked for me on local env (not GAE).

If you follow [django-pipeline official guide](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#jinja) it states, that you should add `pipeline.templatetags.ext.PipelineExtension` to your environment, which for me meant updating my `settings.py` to this:

```
# myproject/settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
    ...
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'environment': 'myproject.jinja2.environment',
            'extensions': ['pipeline.templatetags.ext.PipelineExtension']
        }
    }
]
```

How to migrate your template? For me it was dead easy, I just removed `{% load pipeline %}` from top of the template and it worked.

Comment: For people looking at this and wanting to use pipeline 1.7 instead of 1.5, the documentation shows that the `'extension'` should read `'pipeline.jinja2.PipelineExtension'` instead of `'pipeline.templatetags.ext.PipelineExtension'`.